# Mock fetch redirect in tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redirect, fetch, sinon

I'm trying to test behaviour following a redirect request performed with fetch API.

I've been using sinon to mock `window.fetch` and have it return the desired response. Here's what I do, simplified:

```
windowFetch = sinon.stub(window, 'fetch');

windowFetch.withArgs('http://example.com/resource')
           .returns(Promise.resolve(new Response(body, {
               status: 200,
               headers: new Headers(headers)
           })));
```

This works fine for standard responses. To handle redirects I want to access the `Response#url` property but I haven't found a way to have it set in unit tests.

It's not possible to set it using the `new Response()` constructor and it's read only so I also can't do that.

Finally, I tried calling `Response.redirect(toAddr)` but it creates the redirect response and the one that follows. The one the browser transparently returns.